# Difference between creating javascript objects

Tags: javascript

When creating an object to use JS in an OO manner, is there any difference within a JS engine between (with the exception of being able to define a constructor:

```
var Uploader = Uploader || {};
```

and

```
var Uploader = function() {

}
```

and

```
function Uploader() {

}
```

Especially when later, you wish to do something along the lines of

```
Uploader.DOM = {    
    Create: function(file) {

    }
};
```

Is it all down to personal preference? Or is there a real difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Objects:**

```
var MyObj = {
    myArr: [1,2,3],
    find: function(/*some arguments*/) {
        //some logic that finds something in this.myArr
    }
}
```

In `MyObj.find` function `this` keyword will point to `MyObj` (which somewhat resembles how `this` works in languages those have classes). You can use this functionality to do **mix-ins**:

```
var MyObj2 = {
    myArr: [4,2,6]
}

MyObj2.find = MyObj.find;
```

In `MyObj2.find` function `this` keyword will point to `MyObj2`.

Also objects support getters and setters (works on IE9+ and all good browsers):

```
var MyObj = {
    myArr: [1,2,3],
    find: function(/*some arguments*/) {
        //some logic that finds something in this.myArr
    },
    get maxValue() {
        return Math.max.apply(null, this.myArr);// maxValue is calculated on the fly
    },
    a_: null,
    get a () {
        return this.a_;
    },
    set a (val) {
        //fire a change event, do input validation
        this.a_ = val;
    }
}
```

Now max value in the array can be accessed like this: `MyObj.maxValue`. I also added a property `a_`. It can't be named the same as its getter and setter so appended an underscore. Appending or prepending underscores is a naming convention for private variables which should not be accessed directly.

```
var qwe = MyObj.a // get a_
MyObj.a = 'something'; //set a_
```

**Functions:**

```
var u = new Uploader(); // will throw an exception
var Uploader = function() { }
```

Uploader is defined in runtime here. It does not exist yet when I try to instantiate it.

```
var u = new Uploader(); //will work
function Uploader() {}
```

Uploader is defined in compilation time here so it will work.

Functions can be used with revealing pattern to conceal some members. Functions don't support getters and setters but you can put objects inside functions.

```
function myFunc() {
    function privateFunc() {};
    function publicFunc() {};
    var obj = {
        //members, getters, setters
    };
    return {
       publicFunc: publicFunc,
       obj: obj
    }
}
```

You can call `muFunc.publicFunc()` outside of `myFunc` because it is returned. But you can not use `privateFunc` outside because it is not returned.
Revealing pattern functions are not meant to be instantiated usually. This is because when you instantiate it everything inside will be copied to a new instance. So it will use up more memory than if you would add functions using `prototype`.

```
myFunc.prototype.someFunc = function() {};
```

Like this all instances of `myFunc` will share the same instance of `someFunc`.

Conclusion: with functions you can simulate a `private` access modifier but in objects the `this` keyword acts somewhat similar of what you'd expect in a language that have classes. But you always can use `call`, `apply` and `bind` to change the context (i.e. what 'this' keyword will be) of the function.